# How to run a basic "Hello World" GLSL program in windows?

Tags: c++, windows, opengl, windows-7, glut

I am trying to run a GLSL program from [this site](http://www.cs.unm.edu/~angel/BOOK/INTERACTIVE_COMPUTER_GRAPHICS/FIFTH_EDITION/PROGRAMS/CHAPTER09/PHONG/phongV.c) and getting this error as below. What are the basic libraries I need to install excluding opengl? I need this in Windows machine.

```
main.cpp:72:30: error: 'GLchar' does not name a type
main.cpp:72:38: warning: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'vShaderFile' with no type [-fpermissive]
main.cpp:72:57: error: 'GLchar' does not name a type
main.cpp:72:65: warning: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'fShaderFile' with no type [-fpermissive]
main.cpp: In function 'void initShader(const int*, const int*)':
main.cpp:75:5: error: 'GLchar' was not declared in this scope
main.cpp:75:13: error: 'vSource' was not declared in this scope
main.cpp:75:23: error: 'fSource' was not declared in this scope
main.cpp:80:43: error: cannot convert 'const int*' to 'const char*' for argument '1' to 'char* readShaderSource(const char*)'
main.cpp:83:43: error: cannot convert 'const int*' to 'const char*' for argument '1' to 'char* readShaderSource(const char*)'
main.cpp:88:30: error: 'GL_VERTEX_SHADER' was not declared in this scope
main.cpp:88:46: error: 'glCreateShader' was not declared in this scope
main.cpp:89:30: error: 'GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER' was not declared in this scope
main.cpp:90:31: error: 'glCreateProgram' was not declared in this scope
main.cpp:94:36: error: 'glAttachShader' was not declared in this scope
main.cpp:99:39: warning: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'type name' with no type [-fpermissive]
main.cpp:99:39: warning: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'type name' with no type [-fpermissive]
main.cpp:99:33: error: expected primary-expression before 'const'
main.cpp:99:33: error: expected ')' before 'const'
main.cpp:100:39: warning: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'type name' with no type [-fpermissive]
main.cpp:100:39: warning: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'type name' with no type [-fpermissive]
main.cpp:100:33: error: expected primary-expression before 'const'
main.cpp:100:33: error: expected ')' before 'const'
main.cpp:104:28: error: 'glCompileShader' was not declared in this scope
main.cpp:109:28: error: 'GL_COMPILE_STATUS' was not declared in this scope
main.cpp:109:54: error: 'glGetShaderiv' was not declared in this scope
main.cpp:117:26: error: 'glLinkProgram' was not declared in this scope
main.cpp:118:28: error: 'GL_LINK_STATUS' was not declared in this scope
main.cpp:123:25: error: 'glUseProgram' was not declared in this scope
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With an error like this

> ```
> main.cpp:72:30: error: 'GLchar' does not name a type
> ```

I'd start by adding the right include directives into my source code. I can't tell you more, without you posting some actual source code.

#### Update

In the linked source code there is this:

```
#include <GLUT/glut.h>
```

`GLUT/glut.h` is not a standard location for the GLUT headers, hence all these errors. If I had to make an educated guess, then this program was written on MacOS X. Only on MacOS X you can use newer OpenGL functions (like shaders) without jumping through some hoops (loading extensions and newer version functions at runtime), at the cost of MacOS X not really keeping up with newer OpenGL versions.

I recommend installing GLEW (available from http://glew.sf.net) and substitute for the following

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
```

and adding a call to `glewInit()` **after** `glutCreateWindow(…)`.

Comment: I have linked the code where I took from.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should take a few steps back, read http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/. It has tutorials and a chapter on how to build them.